# Error HRESULT: [0xC00D36B4] when recording screen from extended screen in sharpDx c#

Tags: c#, directx, ms-media-foundation, sharpdx, screen-recording

I want to use a screen recording program that I downloaded from github. Program link: [enter link description here](https://github.com/Shehryar/Duplicator)

My system has two screens. I have no problem taking the first screen recording. But when I record the second screen (extended screen), an error occurs this line :

```
writer.SetInputMediaType(_videoOutputIndex, video, null); 
Error :  **SharpDX.SharpDXException: 'HRESULT: [0xC00D36B4]**
```

I request support from experts.

good work.

```
 using (var video = new MediaType())
            {
                video.Set(MediaTypeAttributeKeys.MajorType, MediaTypeGuids.Video);
                video.Set(MediaTypeAttributeKeys.Subtype, VideoFormatGuids.Rgb32);
                video.Set(MediaTypeAttributeKeys.FrameSize, ((long)width << 32) | (uint)height);
                if (Options.RecordingFrameRate != 0)
                {
                    video.Set(MediaTypeAttributeKeys.FrameRate, ((long)frameRateNumerator << 32) | (uint)frameRateDenominator);
                }

                Trace("Add Video Input Media Type");
                writer.SetInputMediaType(_videoOutputIndex, video, null);
            }
```

Comment: Don't use screenshot for stack traces https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors plus not everyone can read everyone's language. Also, show what's in [External Code]. It's probably a problem specific with your PC, hardware or drivers.

Comment: Thank you for your warning and suggestions. I did not make any additions to the software. I downloaded it from Github and used it. It gave such an error when I recorded from the second screen. I will check my drivers.

Comment: @SimonMourier I have tried updating the drivers and tried on several different computers but the error persists.

Comment: This is usually because the hardware does not support or expect the exact set of media type attributes another hardware expect. Try to set Options.RecordingFrameRate, for example to 60

Comment: @SimonMourier When I set the value to 60, I can take screen recording from the extended screen, but on the condition that the microphone is turned off... when I turn the microphone on, it gives an error again.

Comment: Yes, this code is not perfect, that's why I removed it from my original github repo but some guys have had the time to copy it before... You'll have to figure out the issue with the sound